# How to iterate through posts and make groups in Ghost

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, handlebars.js, ghost-blog

Hello fellow ghost writers,

I am basically developping my own theme based on Bootstrap. Therefore I want to create a carousel of links to article. I display 3 Bootstraps cards and I would like to add a caroussel.
It is fairly easy as I just need to make a caroussel of card decks and put 3 cards per card deck.

But, there is a problem... How I tell Ghost to iterate through all posts and create "groups" of three posts ? Put differently: "foreach posts and every 3 posts do..."

I actually have:

```
        {{#foreach posts limit="3"}}
            {{> "post-card"}}
        {{/foreach}}
```

And I need something like:

```
        {{#foreach posts}}
            {{every 3 items}}
                <div class="card-deck">
                    {{> "post-card"}}
                </div>
        {{/foreach}}
```

I have really no idea how to start with that.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done using `@rowStart` and `@rowEnd` when setting a `columns` value on the `#foreach` loop. Here's an example:

```html
{{#foreach posts columns="3"}}
    {{#if @rowStart}}<div class="card-deck">{{/if}}
        {{> "post-card"}}
    {{#if @rowEnd}}</div>{{/if}}
{{/foreach}}
```

By setting a `columns` to `3` `@rowStart` will signal the beginning of a column and `@rowEnd` will signal the end of a column.

More info can be found in the Ghost handlebars docs: https://ghost.org/docs/api/v3/handlebars-themes/helpers/foreach/#data-variables

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much. I went through the docs of ghost and handlebars and missed that. It works